# Limit of the complements of closed points.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, limits-colimits, function-fields

Given a scheme let's say $\mathbb{A}^n$ over a field $k$. The limit of all open subschemes is given by the spectrum of the function field i.e. $\text{Spec}(k(x_1,\ldots, x_n))$. Now consider the open subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n$ that are complements of a finite union of closed points (dimension zero closed subschemes). Does the limit of these open subschemes exit as a scheme? (transition maps are not affine) If so is it the same as $\text{Spec}(k(x_1,\ldots, x_n))$?

Comment: What, precisely, is the diagram you are considering? The obvious diagram of "all open subschemes" has a terminal object, namely the scheme itself, so the colimit is the same thing. The same holds for the diagram of "all open subschemes that are complements of a finite set of closed points". Furthermore $\operatorname{Spec} k [x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ itself.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. It should have been limit not colimit.